# How to access windows enviroment variables on MSYS?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, ffmpeg, msys

I want to build ffmpeg by vs2015 from msys2.

In the first add vs2015\vc\bin\amd64 in to path enviroment in windows.

Run "vs2015 x64 command prompt" as administrator then run vcvarsall.bat amd64.

In the final go to "msys" path and then run "msys2_shell.cmd".

I use "which cl" command for localize cl.exe.

**Output:**

> which: no cl in 
>   (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/)

How to access to windows enviroments in the msys ?

Comment: Can't reproduce, though I'm just first running the vs2015 x64 command prompt and then msys2_shell as that is sufficient. There's really no need to add something to the path first, nor to run vcvarsall twice (the vs command prompts just run vsvarsall.bat) What's the output of `echo %PATH%` when you are at the vs prompt, i.e. does it find cl? If not, vcvarsall is broken, else msys is broken since it's supposed to take over the whole environment

Answer (score 9):

Ran into the same problem.

Cause:

> The `PATH` environment variable is not inherited to msys2.

Solution:

> Rather than run `msys2_shell.cmd` alone, run it with a `-use-full-path` parameter:

```
 msys2_shell.cmd -use-full-path
```