# Need help to compile FFmpeg with MSVC tools

Tags: visual-studio, ffmpeg, msys

I need to compile FFmpeg on Windows 10 using MSVC 2017 compiler. I followed some guides from:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC
- https://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows
- https://pracucci.com/compile-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-visual-studio-compiler.html

I installed current stable version of MSYS, fixed link.exe and use of PATH environment, installed `make diffutils gcc pkg-config` and downloaded c99-to-c89, nasm, and inttypes.h

I think my environment is now correctly set up, I ran MSYS shell from MSVC Command prompt and have everything reachable.

```
$ which cl
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/HostX64/x64/cl

$ which link
/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/HostX64/x64/link

$ which yasm
/home/Antoine/bin/yasm

$ which c99conv
/home/Antoine/bin/c99conv

$ which c99wrap
/home/Antoine/bin/c99wrap
```

Now I configure the build

```
$ ./configure --toolchain=msvc
install prefix            /usr/local
source path               .
C compiler                cl
C library                 msvcrt
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
standalone assembly       yes
x86 assembler             nasm
MMX enabled               yes
MMXEXT enabled            yes
3DNow! enabled            yes
3DNow! extended enabled   yes
SSE enabled               yes
SSSE3 enabled             yes
AESNI enabled             yes
AVX enabled               yes
AVX2 enabled              yes
XOP enabled               yes
FMA3 enabled              yes
FMA4 enabled              yes
i686 features enabled     yes
CMOV is fast              yes
EBX available             no
EBP available             no
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             no
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    no
network support           yes
threading support         w32threads
safe bitstream reader     yes
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              no
pod2man enabled           no
makeinfo enabled          no
makeinfo supports HTML    no

External libraries:
schannel                 xlib

External libraries providing hardware acceleration:
cuda                     cuvid                    d3d11va                  dxva2                    nvenc

Libraries:
avcodec                  avdevice                 avfilter                 avformat                 avutil                   swresample               swscale

Programs:
ffmpeg                   ffprobe

[...]
Hundreds of modules, library, etc.
[...]

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later
Creating configuration files ...
config.h is unchanged
config.asm is unchanged
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged
libavcodec/bsf_list.c is unchanged
libavformat/protocol_list.c is unchanged
```

But when I run `make` it stops very quickly

```
$ make
Makefile:47: la cible « qt-faststart » ne correspond pas au motif de cible
Makefile:47: la cible « trasher » ne correspond pas au motif de cible
Makefile:47: la cible « uncoded_frame » ne correspond pas au motif de cible
Makefile:91: ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « ffbuild/library.mak ». Arrêt.
```

Sorry for the french wording, I don't know how to tell MSVC print its output in english. Basically, the error means:

```
Makefile:47: target « qt-faststart » doesn't match the target pattern
make: *** No rule to make target « ffbuild/library.mak ». Stopped.
```

Side notes:

```
$ tree ffbuild
ffbuild
├── config.fate
├── config.log
├── config.mak
└── config.sh
```

That's right, library.mak were not generated into ffbuild, but I don't know why, and configure script didn't output any error message...

Does anybody can help me to find out what am I doing wrong ?

**Edit:**

`make distclean` doesn't help

```
$ make distclean
Makefile:47: la cible « qt-faststart » ne correspond pas au motif de cible
Makefile:47: la cible « trasher » ne correspond pas au motif de cible
Makefile:47: la cible « uncoded_frame » ne correspond pas au motif de cible
Makefile:91: ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « ffbuild/library.mak ». Arrêt.
```

Comment: If the source is up-to-date, do a `make distclean` and try again.

Comment: @Mulvya thanks, your comment helped me ! I tried to re-download source archive from ffmpeg github, and now the `make` command works well. I previously used archive ffmpeg-3.4.1.tar.bz2 but it was probably corrupted, or badly unarchived.

Answer (score 2):

I finally succeeded to compile FFmpeg on Windows after re-downloading sources as zip package from [github](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg). I previously downloaded sources from ffmpeg.org but the archive (.tar.bz2) was probably corrupted and/or the extraction failed at some point.

Comment: For others coming here looking for a way to compile FFmpeg for VS2017, if you use MSYS2 then you might have to add `-use-full-path` when running MSYS shell from MSVC Command. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810726/5195136)